# Socket.Bind then connect on MS Loopback NIC

Tags: c#, java, windows, tcp, loopback

I have created a loopback Interface card in **Windows 7 x64**

say the IP of my **local machine** is

20.200.20.**30** / 
255.255.255.128

and the IP of **Loopback adapter** is

20.200.20.**65** / 255.255.255.128

I open up a listening socket on 20.200.20.30 on port 7800

On another thread/applciation i bind a socket on 20.200.20.65 and then connect 20.200.20.30
but it fails with *connection time out*.

It worked well on windows XP though.

Please advise

Comment: You try to `connect()` from the same socket you just `bind()`?

Comment: Sort of, i bind to 65(Loopback) then connect to 30(physical NIC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

All i had to do was to enable weakhost for both the NICs

netsh interface ipv4 set interface “MainNIC” weakhostsend=enabled
netsh interface ipv4 set interface “MainNIC” weakhostreceive=enabled

netsh interface ipv4 set interface “LoopbackNIC” weakhostsend=enabled
netsh interface ipv4 set interface “LoopbackNIC” weakhostreceive=enabled

Answer (score 1):

Binding the outbound socket to the loopback address and then trying to connect it to a non-loopback address doesn't make any sense. Just skip the bind step. There's very little reason to ever do this outside VPNs, which this is not.

Comment: I was actually testing a code that needs multiple PCs to run so attempting to simulate the environment of multiple NICs. To skip the bind step requires code change which i dont want to do.

Comment: @BasitAnwer OK so bind it to the address you are sending to. The loopback adapter can only loop back.

Comment: in windows XP it worked fine, i have tried enabling weakHostsend and recieve

Comment: @BasitAnwer I don't understand the purpose in doing it wrong, regardless of whether it happens to work on some specific platform.

Comment: The reason i am doing this is there are multiple NICs in the environment where it needs to be deployed so binding is the most suitable option if a specific IP is defined in config.